# How to unset all fields except some known fields?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, mongodb-query, pymongo

I need to delete some fields of a document, but I only know the fields that I want to keep. How do I $unset all but my known fields. For instance:

A document in my Database looks like the following

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("1234567891234"),
  "name" : "testname",
  "settings" : {
    "pairing" : true}
  "subject" : "alarm"
}
```

And I want to delete the "Settings" and the "Subject" field. So it will be like the following.

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("1234567891234"),
  "name" : "testname"
}
```

However I cant just use "$unset" to a field, because I only know the fields that I want to keep.

Is there a way to do this in pymongo. I've found a related question but I have no idea if this is at all possible in python 2.7.

Related question:
[How do I unset all fields except a known set of fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459086/in-mongo-how-do-i-unset-all-fields-except-a-known-set-of-fields)

Comment: Yes it is possible. I've also added an answer to that question to show how to do this in the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible! The best way to do this if you want to unset all fields except the *known* fields for multiple documents in your collection is to use "bulk" operations.

MongoDB 3.2 deprecates [`Bulk()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/bulk.html#module-pymongo.bulk) and its associated methods. So if you should use the [`.bulk_write()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.bulk_write).

```
from itertools import zip_longest # or izip_longest in Python 2.x
from pymongo import MongoClient, UpdateOne


client = MongoClient()
db = client.db
collection = db.collection
requests = []
fields = ['name', '_id']
for document in collection.find():
    unset_op = dict(zip_longest(set(document.keys()).difference(fields), [''], fill_value='')) 
    requests.append(UpdateOne({'_id': document['_id']}, {'$unset': unset_op}))
    # Execute per 1000 operations and re-init.
    if len(requests) == 1000:
        collection.bulk_write(requests)
        requests = []

# clean up the queues
if requests:
    collection.bulk_write(requests)
```

For a single document you need to use the [`find_one`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one) method which return the document that matches your criteria and then [`replace_one`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.replace_one) new in version 3.0

```
document = collection.find_one({'_id': 111})
collection.replace_one({'_id': document['_id']}, dict(zip(fields, [document[field] for field in fields])))
```

---

If you are not using the latest version of MongoDB or Pymongo driver you need to use the `Bulk()` API.

```
bulk = collection.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()
count = 0
for document in collection.find():
    unset_op = dict(zip_longest(set(document.keys()).difference(fields), [''], fill_value=''))
    bulk.find({'_id': document['_id']}).update_one({'$unset': unset_op})
    count = count + 1
    if count % 1000 == 0:
        bulk.execute()
        bulk = collection.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()        
    if count > 0:
        bulk.execute()
```

For a single document you can rely on the [`update_one`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one) method.

```
unset_op = dict(izip_longest(set(document.keys()).difference(fields), [''], fill_value=''))
collection.update_one({'_id': document['_id']}, {'$unset': unset_op})
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to update without the "$set" that way it will update the whole document removing the unspecified fields for example:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("1234567891234"),
  "name" : "testname",
  "settings" : {
    "pairing" : true}
  "subject" : "alarm"
}
```

doing

```
db.collection_name.update({"_id" : ObjectId("1234567891234")},{"name" : "testname"})
```

will result in the other fields removed but *"name"*.
So in python you can do the following:

```
result = db.collection_name.find_one({"name":"testname"})
```

(If you know the ids you can search but be sure to import `from bson.objectid import ObjectId`). After that you have the collection stored in result. then you want to update with the records you know of example:

```
db.collection_name.update_one({"_id":result["_id"]},{"name":result["name"]})
```

This is one way to do it. It will only keep "name" and the "_id" of course but all other unspecified fields will be removed. Hope it helps